# How do you set a UIImage using an absolute URL?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to set the UIImage of a tableview cell to an absolute url, here's the code i have already:

```
NSString * imageURL = [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"images"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
//set image
cell.imageView.image = img;
```

But for some reason this returns null as if the URL supplied is invalid. However i know this is not the case because i can make it work by typing one of the URLs as a string literal into the imageURL pointer and i know the code  [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"images"] returns correct URLs as i printed the output to the log and it was fine.

Is there any reason why this would be happening that I'm clearly not seeing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`absoluteURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method of `NSURL` and voila!

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] absoluteURL];
```